# rcpp matrix multiplication speed improvement

Tags: performance, matrix, eigen, rcpp, armadillo

I am using Rcpp for some heavy computation. However, my code doesn't run as fast as expected. I know I must have done something wrong because the same computation is faster in MATLAB. I have a hard time figuring out how I could improve my code, so I'm genuinely asking for help here.

I have a 12 by 5000^2/2 matrix called mX, and a 5000^2/2 by 1 matrix called w.
I would like to calculate A=mX * diag(w) * t(mX).

I have written the following four functions to do it.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]
// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppEigen")]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
using namespace Rcpp; 
using Eigen::MatrixXd;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat MultiplyArma1(arma::mat mX, arma::colvec w){
  return mX*arma::diagmat(w)*arma::trans(mX);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat MultiplyArma2(arma::mat mX, arma::colvec w){
  return mX*(arma::repmat(w,1,12)%arma::trans(mX));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat MultiplyCpp(arma::mat mX, arma::colvec w){ 
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    int N=mX.n_rows;
    int K=mX.n_cols;
    arma::mat tmX=arma::zeros<arma::mat>(K,N);
    arma::mat ProductF=arma::zeros<arma::mat>(N,N);
    arma::mat ProductM=arma::zeros<arma::mat>(K,N);

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int i=0; i<K; ++i){
      for (int j=0; j<N; ++j){     
            tmX(i,j)=mX(j,i);
        }
    }


    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int j=0; j<N; ++j){
        for (int i=0; i<K; ++i){
            ProductM(i,j)=tmX(i,j)*w(i);
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int j=0; j<N; ++j){
        for (int i=0; i<N; ++i){
          for (int k=0; k<K; ++k){
            ProductF(i,j) +=tmX(k,i)*ProductM(k,i);
          }
        }
    }
    return ProductF;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
MatrixXd MultiplyEigen(const MatrixXd mX, const MatrixXd Dw){
  return mX* ( Dw.cwiseProduct( mX.transpose() ) );   
}
```

The 1st and 2nd both use RcppArmadillo, and only differs in representation of diag(w). The 3rd makes use of openmp, and I code up everthing element wise. The 4th uses RcppEigen. I don't know how to generate diag(w) in RcppEigen, so I have the input be Dw=rep(w,1,12).

```
mX=matrix(0.7, 12, 5000^2/2)
w=matrix(0.2, 5000^2/2,1)
Dw=repmat(w, 1,12)

tic()
a1=MultiplyArma1(mX,w)
toc()

tic()
a2=MultiplyArma2(mX,w)
toc()

tic()
a3=MultiplyCpp(mX,w)
toc()

tic()
a4=MultiplyEigen(mX, Dw)
toc()
```

Then as I time the speed, They all take more than 3 seconds. However, when I do the same calculation in MATLAB  `A=mX*(repmat(w,1,12).*mX')`, it takes only 1.5 seconds.

It makes me feel that there's still room for improving my Rcpp function, but I honestly don't know how. I would very much appreciate your help!

Comment: To a first approximation. Matlab may be using an optimised BLAS library whereas your R installation (and hence RcppArmadillo) is not.  Those things matter.

Comment: Thank you, @DirkEddelbuettel ! Is there a way that I can make use of such BLAS library in Rcpp? How do I do that? Honestly I don't have any prior experience with compiled language, and I am really struggling.

Comment: This matrix multiplication part is really slowing down my code. Any solution/workaround is greatly appreciated. Additionally, I feel that the expression I'm trying to evaluate has a specific structure. Is there a way to make use of the structure and speed up the code?

Comment: This is not something for a one-line answer.  See the vignette of my `gcbd` package, and consult a local Linux expert, for more on different BLAS libraries.

Comment: Almost surely MATLAB is using MKL. In case you are using the BLAS that ships with R I would strongly recommend switch to OpenBLAS.